# Angular 2 RC5 providers at component level get new instance every time

Tags: javascript, angular

Until RC5 we could declare providers at component level like this:

```
@Component({
  providers: [SomeService]
})
```

And every component would get a new instance of SomeService, but now with RC5 the component providers as been deprecated so how we achieve this effect?

Comment: Could you please go through [rc4 to rc5 migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)?

Comment: I did! but not found or missed the answer...

Comment: I dont think this question is true. if you follow the quick start it still calls in services as providers in components....

Comment: Where? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html ? here?

Comment: follow the link in my answer and scroll down to the bottom where is shows the tabbed view with all three components.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the quick start [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) services have not really changed. Still need the 4 core things

1. A service is created via injectable

2.import that service into component

3.provide that service

4 and construct it in the export

Comment: Read this http://angularjs.blogspot.co.il/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html

Comment: yes, this explains the new concept of module for rc.5 (also in the quickstart) however the official docs still use services the way I explained above.

Comment: I think this is because they are still support RC4.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a factory method to your service that returns a new instance.

```
export class SomeService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    create() {
        return new SomeService(this.http);
    }

}
```

That is very much a hack and requires you to call create in your components.

It seems the subscribed solution is to use a [Factory Provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#factory-providers).

Essentially you create factory method and provider object:

```
import { Http }  from '@angular2/core';
import { SomeService } from './SomeService';

let someServiceFactory = (http: Http) => {
    return new SomeService(http);
};

export let SomeServiceProvider =
  { provide: SomeService,
     useFactory: someServiceFactory,
     deps: [Http]
  };
```

So now you inject `SomeService` as you did before, and you will always get a new `transient` instance.

Import the provider into your module or component and register it as `providers: [someServiceProvider]`

Or inline it as:

```
providers: [{ 
    provide: SomeService, 
    useFactory: (http: Http) => { return new SomeService(http)}, 
    deps: [Http]
}]
```